# C# MySQL reader is not reading

Tags: c#, mysql, sqldatareader

I have a function that reads values from specified columns. It looks like this:

```
        private bool OpenConnection() // Just opens the connection. No error here.
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection not opened");
                return false;
            }
        }
    private void getStats(string user, string cate, string score)
    {
        if (OpenConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                string getuserstats = $"SELECT {cate} FROM scores WHERE user = '{user}'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getuserstats, conn);
                MySqlDataReader getscore = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show(getscore.Read().ToString()); //outputs false.
                while(getscore.Read())//does not run
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Reading!");//does not run
                    score = getscore.GetString(0);//does not run
                    MessageBox.Show(score); //does not run
                }
                getscore.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error getting scores!");
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection not opened!");
        }
    }
```

The SQL command part seems to run fine, I tested it with some different querys and they all worked fine.

However, the SQL reader itself doesn't seem to run. I do not get an exception error either.

I used a message box to show the boolean value of my reader reading, and it outputted false. Why is this?

Comment: Did you try running `getuserstats` directly on workbench? Does it give you any result there?

Comment: Yes. I ran getuserstats in workbench and it worked perfectly. The curly braces worked for other sql codes and readers as well.

Comment: Use the debugger and check what are the values for user and cate. We can't reproduce your situation. The code is formally correct albeit it could be used to start an Sql Injection hack on your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason that `Read()` returns false is that no records match the query that you're performing. Are you sure there are any records in that table matching the given user name? And that the database you are connecting to is the one you think it's connecting to.

This won't be related, but the MySqlCommand and MySqlDataReader are both disposable, as is the connection, so you should place them in "using" blocks, or explicitly dispose them.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the original code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - the *user* should be passed as a parameter to the query, rather than by constructing the string yourself. For example, if *user* = "O'Reilly", your code will crash.